# Fetching kendo grid row data on selecting checkbox

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-dataviz

I am trying to fetch kendo data on selecting particular row using checkbox.

This is part of code of controller.js

```
$scope.campaignLabelOptions = {
            dataSource: {
                data: [] ,
            },

            sortable: true,
            pageable : {pageSizes : [5, 10, 25, 50]},
            filterable : true,
            resizable  :true,
            reordable :true,
            scrollable:true,
            columnMenu: true,
            selectable :true,
            editable: {
                confirmation: "Are you sure that you want to delete this record?",
                mode: "popup"
            }, 
            columns : [
                  {template: "<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' ng-click='onClick($event)'/>" },
                  {field : "campaign_name", title :"Campaign Name", width : "150px", attributes: {style: "font-size: 12px"}},
                  // {field : "time_line", title :"Timeline", width : "100px",attributes: {style: "font-size: 12px"} },
                  {field : "spend", title :"Spend", width : "90px",attributes: {style: "font-size: 12px"} },
                  {field : "campaign_group_status", title :"Status", width : "85px", attributes: {style: "font-size: 12px"}},
                  {field : "performance", title :"Performance", width : "130px", attributes: {style: "font-size: 12px"}},
                  // {field : "creation_time", title :"Created Time", width : "135px", attributes: {style: "font-size: 12px"}},                
                  ],
        }; 




$scope.checkedIds = [];
        $scope.showCheckboxes = function(){
          var checked = [];
          for(var i in $scope.checkedIds){
            if($scope.checkedIds[i]){
              checked.push(i);
            }
          }
          alert(checked);
        };

        $scope.onClick = function(e){
          console.log(e);
          var element =$(e.currentTarget);

          var checked = element.is(':checked'); 
          var row = element.closest("tr"); 
          var grid = element.closest('kendoGrid').getKendoGrid(); 
          var dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);

          $scope.checkedIds[dataItem.EmployeeID] = checked;
          if (checked) {
            row.addClass("k-state-selected");
          } else {
            row.removeClass("k-state-selected");
          }
        };
```

I have copied similar code from http://dojo.telerik.com/exAB/5  for select logic . But here grid variable is coming undefined. Its not getting getKendoGrid()  method..

Is there any better way to get row data? If yes what  and if not -- how to use this current code?

Comment: In `var grid = element.closest('kendoGrid').getKendoGrid(); ` did you check what is `element.closest('kendoGrid');`? Shouldn't it be `element.closest('kendo-grid')`

Comment: This element.closest('kendoGrid') and element.closest('kendo-grid')  printing same details, but   getting undefined on attaching getKendoGrid()

Comment: Is getKendoGrid()  is already defined method as in http://dojo.telerik.com/exAB/5

Comment: The example that you refer to is working fine, correct? In that example if you change it to `element.closest('kendoGrid');` then it stops working. If `getKendoGrid` fails is because whatever you are selecting with `element.closest('kendoGrid')` is actually not a grid.